ETHM tranf from BNB Smart network to Luno ECR 20
Good day
Please assist.
We transferred a very large amount of ETHM from our coinbase wallet to our luno ETH wallet. The transaction shows on the blockchain but not in the wallet. We have attempted to get assistance from coinbase and luno to reverse the transaction, however with no assistance. They both say the funds are lost. Its a very large value and we cannot afford the loss, can anyone help us recover our funds please

Can you share the transaction hash? Without details we can only provide general suggestions: transactions on blockchains are final and cannot be reverted. Only the recipient can create reverse a transaction to return funds, but it will be a new transaction. Common ERC20 transfers work within the same network. To tranfer between networks you have to use a bridge. In that case I'd recommend to use your own wallet and not centralized wallets because they usually don't cooperate in case of a mistake.

@ismael Please see as requested, but its not reflecting on Etherscan, only on Bsc scan 0xf6Fb001532ef92DeBaE37F5e63bA436DC239Ce1f. We have been in contact with Luno and Coinbase and Metamask. Metamask says its do able to retrieve our lost funds, Luno says they cannot give us the pvt key, so we stuck as we need the pvt key. Can we obtain the pvt key another way?

That address doesn't have any transaction on the principal networks. What network did you use to make the transfer? Private keys aren't meant to be shared. Luno won't be able to recover your funds if you sent them to an unsupported network. For centralized exchanges private keys are stored inside hardware devices for security reasons. They aren't easy to manipulate for unsupported networks.
